Cannot display image in Vue.js + Laravel + Inertia
I need help with displaying images within a Vue.js component in my project, which is integrated with Laravel and Inertia.
I have a component called "Index.vue" located at the route "http://127.0.0.1:8000/clases". This component displays each "clase" stored in my database. Each "clase" item contains a link that redirects to its respective "show" view, with URLs such as "http://127.0.0.1:8000/clases/5". Within the "show" component, I've included another component named "Anuncios.vue", where I'm attempting to display the image.
<script setup>
const props = defineProps({
    data: Object,
    clase_id: Number,
    errors: Object,
});

const isImage = (data) => {
    const name = data.nombre;

    return name.endsWith(".jpeg");
};

const imageUrl = (url) => {
    return url.replace("public/", "storage/");
};


</script>
<template>
<div v-for="materiale in data.materiales">
    <div v-if="isImage(material)">
        <img :src="imageUrl(materiale.url)" alt="" srcset="">
    </div>
</div>
</template>

However, when attempting to display the images, I encountered the following error in the browser console:
However, when attempting to display the images, I encountered the following error in the browser console:
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/clases/storage/materiales/17128465062.jpeg [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 651ms]
It seems that a "clases/" prefix is added to the URL, which I cannot explain.The "materiale.url" contains a URL like "public/materiales/17128465061.docx". I  replace "public/" with "storage/" to point to the correct "public/storage" link.
Could anyone explain why the "clases/" prefix is added to the URL and help me resolve this issue? Any assistance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Double-check the Network tab to make sure the image isn't being redirected. Also double-check the data.materiales to make sure the URL looks correct.

@aynber I've inspected the Network tab, and it appears that the image URL is not being redirected. Additionally, upon reviewing the data.materiales, the URLs seem to be formatted correctly, without any unexpected prefixes.
Given this information, I'm still unsure why the "clases/" prefix is added to the image URL. Do you have any other suggestions or insights that could help me resolve this issue?
Thank you once again for your assistance!

Try add slash / in the first name of folder, or change the code so it will look like return '/' + url.replace("public/", "storage/");, make sure that storage shortcut is available in public.

Can you see the image with correct url in the browser? If yes, check app name in .env or config/app.php, if /clases/ come from there. Or put full path inside src + imageUrl

    const imageUrl = (url) => {
    return url.replace("public/", "storage/");
};

just delete only "public/" in that const!
works?
